# typedef redefinition in 3rdparty library

Tags: c, typedef

I use `log4cpp` and `libnet` in my project, but there is a problem.

In `log4cpp`,`config-win32.h`

```
typedef u_long in_addr_t
```

Also in `libnet`, `in_systm.h`

```
typedef u_int32_t in_addr_t;
```

So how to fix it elegantly ?

- don't modify the library source
- less work

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid this by using a work around when including the headers:

```
#define in_addr_t log4cpp_in_addr_t
#include "config-win32.h"
#undef in_addr_t

#define in_addr_t libnet_in_addr_t
#include "in_systm.h"
#undef in_addr_t
```

Then in your code, use `log4cpp_in_addr_t` and `libnet_in_addr_t` instead of `in_addr_t`.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe simplify the situation.I include `libnet.h` and `log4cpp` some header.I don't use `in_addr_t`.I'm not sure I have said clearly.

Comment: If you don't use `in_addr_t`, then you don't have to worry about specifying which you intended to use.  This works, though, regardless.  At one level it's a cheat; at another level, it'll get you over the hump.  It would be harder in C++, in general, because type names are baked into function names, etc.  But in C, it'll be OK.  (You might get away with it in C++ too if you never use a function with one of the `in_addr_t` parameter.  If you used the functions with the `in_addr_t` parameters, you'd have to carefully segregate the code using `log4cpp` from the code using `libnet`.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `in_addr_t` with another word in `log4cpp` or `libnet`.

if `in_addr_t` does not appear much. you can move the `typedef……` to a `{}` where you use `in_addr_t`. typedef's scope is `{}` if you use it in block of code.